# Extends DatePickerProps antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import React from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import type { DatePickerProps } from "antd";

interface Props extends DatePickerProps {}

function CustomRangePicker(props: Props) {
  const { ...rest } = props;

  return <DatePicker.RangePicker {...rest} />;
}

export default CustomRangePicker;
```

I want to create a custom component that uses RangePicker antd.

But ts is giving error An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

How can I bind DatePickerProps to interface Props. So that vscode can suggest classes for me